# Error: error during handshake: error on replay: validator set is nil in genesis and still empty after InitChain Usage:

Tags: gaia, cosmos-sdk

I'm trying to start a new node : https://github.com/cosmos/mainnet

It looks like I'm having some issue with `gaiad start`

after I Fetch the mainnet's `genesis.json` file into `gaiad`'s config directory.

```
mkdir -p $HOME/.gaia/config
wget https://github.com/cosmos/mainnet/raw/master/genesis.cosmoshub-4.json.gz
gzip -d genesis.cosmoshub-4.json.gz
mv genesis.cosmoshub-4.json $HOME/.gaia/config
```

and start `gaiad start`

```
error.log:



11:45PM INF starting ABCI with Tendermint
    11:45PM INF Starting multiAppConn service impl=multiAppConn module=proxy
    11:45PM INF Starting localClient service connection=query impl=localClient module=abci-client
    11:45PM INF Starting localClient service connection=snapshot impl=localClient module=abci-client
    11:45PM INF Starting localClient service connection=mempool impl=localClient module=abci-client
    11:45PM INF Starting localClient service connection=consensus impl=localClient module=abci-client
    11:45PM INF Starting EventBus service impl=EventBus module=events
    11:45PM INF Starting PubSub service impl=PubSub module=pubsub
    11:45PM INF Starting IndexerService service impl=IndexerService module=txindex
    11:45PM INF ABCI Handshake App Info hash= height=0 module=consensus protocol-version=0 software-version=
    11:45PM INF ABCI Replay Blocks appHeight=0 module=consensus stateHeight=0 storeHeight=0
    11:45PM INF asserting crisis invariants inv=0/11 module=x/crisis name=bank/nonnegative-outstanding
    11:45PM INF asserting crisis invariants inv=1/11 module=x/crisis name=bank/total-supply
    11:45PM INF asserting crisis invariants inv=2/11 module=x/crisis name=distribution/nonnegative-outstanding
    11:45PM INF asserting crisis invariants inv=3/11 module=x/crisis name=distribution/can-withdraw
    11:45PM INF asserting crisis invariants inv=4/11 module=x/crisis name=distribution/reference-count
    11:45PM INF asserting crisis invariants inv=5/11 module=x/crisis name=distribution/module-account
    11:45PM INF asserting crisis invariants inv=6/11 module=x/crisis name=staking/module-accounts
    11:45PM INF asserting crisis invariants inv=7/11 module=x/crisis name=staking/nonnegative-power
    11:45PM INF asserting crisis invariants inv=8/11 module=x/crisis name=staking/positive-delegation
    11:45PM INF asserting crisis invariants inv=9/11 module=x/crisis name=staking/delegator-shares
    11:45PM INF asserting crisis invariants inv=10/11 module=x/crisis name=gov/module-account
    11:45PM INF asserted all invariants duration=3.224041 height=0 module=x/crisis
    11:45PM INF created new capability module=ibc name=ports/transfer
    11:45PM INF port binded module=x/ibc/port port=transfer
    11:45PM INF claimed capability capability=1 module=transfer name=ports/transfer
    Error: error during handshake: error on replay: validator set is nil in genesis and still empty after InitChain
```